# Showing that the set $S$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Here's the question:

Let $S$ be a set of positive real numbers. There is a constant $M>0$ such that for any $\{ a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k \}\subset S$, we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n\le M \tag{1}$$
Prove that $S$ is at most countable.

---

Here's my attempt:

If $S$ is finite then there is nothing to prove. So, we prove the following:

**Claim.** If $S$ is any infinite set of positive real numbers satisfying condition $(1)$ then $\max S$ exists.

*Proof.* Let $S$ be a set satisfying $(1)$. Then $M$ is an upperbound for the set $S$. By least upper bound axiom, $\alpha=\sup S$ exists. Since $S$ is a set of positive reals, $\alpha >0$. If the maximum existed then it must be equal to $\alpha$. So, suppose that it does not exist. Choose an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $a-\varepsilon >0$. Then by the Archimedean property, $M\le k(\alpha - \varepsilon)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, since $\alpha$ is the supremum and not the maximum, we can select distinct elements $a_1,a_2, \ldots , a_k$ from $S$ such that $\alpha - \varepsilon < a_i < \alpha$ for each $i$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n> k(\alpha - \varepsilon ) \ge M$ but this would contradict our assumption that $(1)$ holds. So, $\alpha$ must be the maximum. $\blacksquare$

Now, let $S$ be any set of positive real numbers satisyfing $(1)$. Then let $a_1= \max S$. Also $S \setminus \{ a_1 \}$ satisfies $(1)$ so, let $a_2=\max (S\setminus\{ a_1 \})$. We repeat this argument to obtain a sequence $\{ a_k \}$ such that $a_k=\max (S\setminus \{ a_1, a_2 , \ldots, a_{k-1} \})$.

Clearly this $\{ a_k \}$ is decreasing and there is no $a\in S$ such that $a_{k+1}<a<a_k$ for any $k$. Also, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges, so, $a_n \to 0$.

If $a \in S\setminus \{a_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ then $a<a_k$ for each $k$. So $a\le0$ (by taking limits) which is not possible. So $S=\{ a_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$.

---

Is this proof correct? **Alternative proofs are also welcome!**

Comment: Is $k$ fixed or it can be any integer value ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien it can be any integer value

Comment: What is $A$ in "we take $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ from $A$ such that..." or "there is no $a\in A$ such that..." ?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I fixed it now. @Tuvasbien

Comment: @ashK you are perhaps over-complicating matters a bit by first establishing your **claim** (not that it weren't correct). What I would do is first use the boundedness condition to show that $S \cap [t, \infty)$ must be finite for arbitrary $t>0$ and to then conclude that $S=\displaystyle\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}_{+}}\left(S \cap [q, \infty)\right)$ must be countable, since it is a countable union of finite (hence countable) sets.

Comment: @ashK Also beware of sloppy syntax: the correct way to express the condition in the problem is: consider a set $S$ such that there exists $a>0$ for which given *any finite* subset $M \subseteq S$ it holds that $\displaystyle\sum_{x \in M}x \leqslant a$ etc. Introducing finite families $a$ of elements of $S$ is not only useless, but also a bit confusing. If instead of the previous condition you meant to refer to the condition: (*to be cont.*)

Comment: @ashK (*cont.*) a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{\times}_{+}$ admitting the existence of real number $a>0$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and *any* family $x \in S^n$ it holds that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \leqslant a$, then it can easily be shown that with neccesity $S=\varnothing$! In other words, this condition involving families is far more restrictive that the one claiming uniformly bounded sums on finite subsets.

Comment: Like it. (See my comment to Brian Scott's A.) It is preferable that, in English, "countable" should mean "finite or countably infinite" so that "uncountable" means the same as "not countable". With this convention, "at most countable" means "countable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn’t hurt to say something to justify the assertion that $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ converges, but the proof is correct. (There is a typo in that sum though: you have $\sum_{\color{red}k=1}^\infty a_{\color{red}n}$.) Here’s a slightly different approach.

Let $\alpha=\sup S>0$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $I_n=\left(2^{-(n+1)}\alpha,2^{-n}\alpha\right]$; then

$$S\subseteq(0,\alpha]=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}I_n\,,$$

and the intervals $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint. There are only countably many of these intervals, so if $S$ is uncountable, there must be an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $S\cap I_n$ is uncountable. But then if $K$ is a $k$-element subset of $A\cap I_n$, we have

$$\sum K>2^{-(n+1)}\alpha k\,,$$

and this can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $k$ large enough, contradicting $(1)$.

Comment: The recursive construction by the OP appeals to me, as it sidesteps AC.  Can it be shown in ZF that a countable union of Tarski-finite subsets of $\Bbb R$ is countable?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I suspect so, since one can use the order of $\Bbb R$ to enumerate their union. (They’re just finite sets; that equivalence is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$.) But in all honesty I don’t care: I consider $\mathsf{AC}$ wholly unproblematic and assume it as a matter of course (unless specifically dealing with consistency questions, of course).

Comment: I follow Mary Ellen Rudin's dictum "Well-order everything in sight". But as soon as I saw the Q, I wondered whether AC was necessary.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: And if that fails, scribble an incomprehensible diagram, then tear a strip off your yellow pad and start meditatively chewing on it. :-) Mary Ellen was my *Doktormutter*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me, an alternative proof could be as follow. Suppose $S$ is not countable and let for $n\geqslant 1$, $S_n=\left\{s\in S,s\geqslant\frac{1}{n}\right\}$. Clearly $\displaystyle S=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}S_n$ and there is at least one $p\geqslant 1$ such that $S_p$ is not countable, otherwise $S$ would be countable as a countable union of countable sets. In particular $S_p$ is infinite so we can take $\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}\subset S_p\subset S$ with $k>pM$. We thus have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k s_n\geqslant\frac{k}{p}>M$ which is not possible and therefore $S$ is countable.